# Inheriting from a generic interface multiple times while respecting variance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I ran into a problem when trying to specialize a class that implements a generic interface where I wanted to inherit from the same interface as the super class, but with a more specific type argument. The following snippet shows a synthetic but complete example that cannot be compiled. The comment contains the error message from the Java compiler.

```
interface Producer<T> {
    T get();
}

class NumberProducer implements Producer<Number> {
    @Override
    public Number get() { return null; }
}

// Producer cannot be inherited with different arguments: <java.lang.Integer> and <java.lang.Number>
class IntegerProducer extends NumberProducer implements Producer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer get() { return null; }
}
```

In the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) sense, `Producer<T>` is a *producer*, so `Producer<Integer>` *would be* a subtype of `Producer<Number>`, but there's no way to declare that in the definition of `Producer<T>`. Java does not allow `IntegerProducer` to inherit from `NumberProducer` and `Producer<Integer>` at the same time as `IntegerProducer` would then inherit from `Producer<Integer>` and `Producer<Number>` at the same time.

Is there a standard approach to this limitation, e.g. a pattern that solves the same problem without requiring this kind of inheritance?

Comment: Why would you want to implement the interface in IntegerProducer? You can override the get() method without implementing the interface as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how these classes are meant to be used? I'm not sure even the common suggestion of making `NumberProducer` generic will do what you want this to do. If you use `NumberProducer<T extends Number> implements Producer<T>`, you can't return anything except `null` from `NumberProducer.get()` because you don't know what subtype of `Number` is `T`. That is, you can't return `new Number()` (I know that constructor doesn't exist, but bear with me) because `T` might, in fact, be `Integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a parameter to the super class:

```
interface Producer<T> {
    T get();
}

class NumberProducer<T extends Number> implements Producer<T> {
    @Override
    public T get() { return null; }
}

class IntegerProducer extends NumberProducer<Integer> { // Implicit: implements Producer<Integer>
    @Override
    public Integer get() { return null; }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I did now, thanks. I introduced a `SpecializableNumberProducer<T extends Number>` and made `NumberProducer` inherit from it without adding any implementation but passing `Number` for the type parameter. This way, users of NumberProducer do not have to explicitly pass `Number` as type parameter on each usage. Ben Schulz's answer has more details on the implementation of generics and what prevents my original code from working.

Answer (score 1):

Say we had a simple Method `gimme`.

```
public static <T> T gimme(Producer<T> p) { return p.get(); }
```

Within the context of `gimme` nothing is known about `T`. It could be `Number`, `Integer` or any other reference type. So, due to erasure, the compiler emits an interface call to `Producer.get()Object` rather than the specific call to, say, `IntegerProducer.get()Integer`. All types that implement `Producer<T>` with `T != Object` also implicitly implement `Producer.get()Object`. This implicit implementation forwards to the specific implementation. That might be `NumberProducer.get()Number` or `IntegerProducer.get()Integer`, *but not both*. That's why you can't implement the same interface twice.

Other languages allow this via definition site variance, where `Producer<Integer>` is a subtype of `Producer<Number>`, but alas, Java does not. The common workaround is to make `NumberProducer` generic as well.

Comment: I do understand that the call `p.get()` in your snippet will be compiled to a call to `Producer.get()Object` which will be implemented by `NumberProducer` but `IntegerProducer` could just override that method and have it call `NumberProducer.get()Integer` so I don't see a problem there.

Comment: @Feuermurmel In languages with declaration site variance that is possible; `IntegerProducer.get()` would override `NumberProducer.get()`. In Java, however, they would be overloaded methods and the compiler could only forward to one of them. Thus it's disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that T is of a specific subtype you can use

```
interface Producer<T extends Number>
```

Not sure what Producer reall is so I have to guess.

Update:
If I understand you correct then I would say, you need to declare an interface which is a Producer. That's simple.

From this interface i would derive a new interface with the respecitve base type.

i.e.:

```
 interface Producer
 {
     base functions
 };


 interface Newproducer<T extends Producer>
 {
 };
```

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: The problem is that I want to use the `Producer` interface for types incompatible with `Number`, e.g. `String`. So I can't put a bound on the type parameter there.

Comment: Updated my approach. Not sure if this is what you had in mind. It also sounds a bit like a factory to me, but without knowing what you intend it's hard to say.